# Issue: All relations are loaded recursively on eloquent model create in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, eager-loading

I have following relationship structure

> Customer has many Orders
>
> Customer has one detail

When I try to create new order like this:

```
$order  = Order::create($data);
```

All the relationship data are loaded recursively & automatically on this `$order` object.

```
Order
- order_id
- product_id
- purchase_date
- customer_id
- customer
    - customer_id
    - customer_name
    - order
         - order_id
         - product_id
         - purchase_date
         - customer_id
    - detail
         - detail_id
         - customer_id
         - address
         - phone
```

I am using laravel 5.5 with php7.2 version as dev environment. What could be the reason behind this ?

Comment: Check if your `Order` model has `protected $with` $with on the model invokes relationships along with the initialization of the model itself

Comment: @RamizKongulov, Thank you for your response. I don't have such `$with` property in Order Model.